# Combine Array From Html To Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I Have An Input type text as Following Code

```
<input type="text" minlength="1" maxlength="1" class="myinputs" name="myinputs[]" >
<input type="text" minlength="1" maxlength="1" class="myinputs" name="myinputs[]" >
<input type="text" minlength="1" maxlength="1" class="myinputs" name="myinputs[]" >
<input type="text" minlength="1" maxlength="1" class="myinputs" name="myinputs[]" >
```

And I use those inputs value as follow

```
//submitotp is my submit button
$("#submitotp").click(function(){
      var otp = $(".myinputs").
      //HERE i WANTS TO COMBINE ALL 4 Input 
}
```

For Example If

```
Input-1 = 5
Input-2 = 4
Input-3 = 9
Input-4 = 2

var otp = 5492 //THIS IS O/p
```

Now What i want is to combine all input value to one. for that i refer this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push). but didn't get any exact idea for this.also hearse about jQuery.merge() but not helpful or not understand. So how can i do this ?

Comment: Shouldn't `class="myinputs[]"` be `name="myinputs[]"`?

Comment: `$("#myinputs")` looks for `id="myinputs"`.

Comment: Why are you using the same name for each input?

Comment: Becuse i need all Value For An 4 Digit OTP. And send to ajax call

Comment: How is this a hot network question?

Comment: m Also Shocked :-!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop using `.each()`, get the value and store/push it in a array variable. You can join the array using `join()`

You also have to rename your class as `myinputs` without `[]`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submitotp").click(function() {
    var otp = [];

    $(".myinputs").each(function() {
      otp.push($(this).val());
    });

    console.log(otp.join(""));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" minlength="1" maxlength="1" class="myinputs">
<input type="text" minlength="1" maxlength="1" class="myinputs">
<input type="text" minlength="1" maxlength="1" class="myinputs">
<input type="text" minlength="1" maxlength="1" class="myinputs">

<button id="submitotp" type="button">Click Me!</button>
```

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Comment: Thank You So Much.!

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: An `.each()` that just appends each value to an array can be replaced with `map()` to make the code simpler.

Answer (score 6):

Get all elements, iterate to get values and finally join them together.

```
// get all elements using the class name
// or using name $('[name="myinputs[]"]')
var res = $('.myinputs')
    // iterate over the elements
    .map(function(){ 
        // return the value
        return this.value; 
    })
    // get result as an array from jQuery object
    .get()
    // join them to generate result string
    .join('');
```

```js
$('#check').click(function() {
  console.log($('.myinputs').map(function() {
    return this.value;
  }).get().join(''));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" minlength="1" maxlength="1" class="myinputs" value="5">
<input type="text" minlength="1" maxlength="1" class="myinputs" value="4">
<input type="text" minlength="1" maxlength="1" class="myinputs" value="9">
<input type="text" minlength="1" maxlength="1" class="myinputs" value="2">

<button id="check">Get OTP</button>
```

---

Without using jQuery

```js
// get all inputs and convert into array
// for newer browser you can use Array.from()
// fonr convertitng into array
var inputs = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.myinputs'));


document.getElementById('check').addEventListener('click', function() {

  console.log(
    // iterate and get value of inputs
    inputs.map(function(ele) {
      return ele.value;
      // join values finally
    }).join('')
  );

  // or using reduce method
  console.log(
    // iterate over elements
    inputs.reduce(function(str, ele) {
      // concatenate with string and return 
      return str + ele.value;
      // set initial value as empty string
    }, '')
  );


});
```

```html
<input type="text" minlength="1" maxlength="1" class="myinputs" value="5">
<input type="text" minlength="1" maxlength="1" class="myinputs" value="4">
<input type="text" minlength="1" maxlength="1" class="myinputs" value="9">
<input type="text" minlength="1" maxlength="1" class="myinputs" value="2">

<button id="check">Get OTP</button>
```

Comment: `.myinputs\\[\\]` Not Understand

Comment: OP mistyped `name="myinputs[]"`

Comment: @Suzan : initially your code only contains class `class="myinputs[]"` , in order to select using a class you need to escape those `[` and `]` since it has special meaning in a selector... now updated answer with new code

Comment: @Suzan : added alternative approach with pure js

Answer (score 3):

Don't put `[]` in `class` attributes. Although it's legal, it makes it harder to access it in jQuery selectors, because `[]` has special meaning there. So use `class="myinputs"`.

Then your selector needs to use `.` to find them, not `#`, which is for selecting by ID.

Once you've done this you can use `.each()` to loop over them and concatenate the values

```js
$("#submitotp").click(function() {
  var otp = "";
  $(".myinputs").each(function() {
    if (this.value) {
      otp += this.value
    }
  });
  console.log(otp);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" minlength="1" maxlength="1" class="myinputs">
<input type="text" minlength="1" maxlength="1" class="myinputs">
<input type="text" minlength="1" maxlength="1" class="myinputs">
<input type="text" minlength="1" maxlength="1" class="myinputs">
<br>
<input type="button" id="submitotp" value="Submit">
```

Answer (score 2):

Few Pointers:

1. Do not use `[]` in your class attributes.
2. Use `.` to use class as a selector.
3. You will need to traverse the input elements to get their value.

```js
$("#submitotp").click(function(){
      var otp = "";
      
      // Traverse through all inputs
      $(".myinputs").each(function(){
           otp += $(this).val();
        }
      );
      console.log(otp);
      
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" minlength="1" maxlength="1" class="myinputs" value="9">
<input type="text" minlength="1" maxlength="1" class="myinputs" value="1">
<input type="text" minlength="1" maxlength="1" class="myinputs" value="3">
<input type="text" minlength="1" maxlength="1" class="myinputs" value="5">

<button id="submitotp">Get OTP</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

this gonna work and easy:

```
var otp = Array.from($(".myinputs")).reduce((re,ele)=>re+ele.value,'')
```

or

```
$(".myinputs").toArray().reduce(function(re,ele){return re+ele.value;},'')
```

Comment: Is this support in Jquery Version 1.0

Comment: actually , this primarily used pure js ,you can test it.first code used ES6 and second used ES5